# How do I paint the treeview node +/- buttons outside a treeview?

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, paint

Similar to the `ButtonRenderer` class, I want to be able to paint the +/- buttons used in `TreeViewNodes` completely separately to any instance of a `TreeView`. There doesn't seem to be a `ControlPaint` method that does it, and drawing a Button doesn't look right. Where can I get the drawing code for a treeview node from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw most parts of the standard Windows controls using the Windows [visual styles API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773187aspx).

I haven't tried rendering a tree view control, but take a look at the .NET [`VisualStyleRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx) class, which appears to wrap all of the functionality of the unmanaged API.

Comment: The link to the TreeView glyphs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.treeview.glyph(v=VS.90).aspx